# Reusing Promise creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to call the getPromise function with different URLs to return different promise, but getting undefined in second promise's then success function.

```
var http=require('http');
var URL='http://localhost:3000';

var getPromise=function(url){
    var promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        http.get(url,function(response){
            if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299){
                reject(new Error('ErrorCode '+response.statusCode))
            }
            var result="";
            response.on('data',function(chunk){result +=chunk;} )
            response.on('end',function(){resolve(result);} )
        })
    });
   return promise;
}



getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
      .then(function(data){
         console.log("Response "+JSON.parse(data).Country);
         getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country);
      })
      .then(function(data){
        console.log("Data "+data)
      })
      .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err)
      });
```

Comment: should you not return the second `getPromise(...)`?

Comment: start use `async/await` and all be clear

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you return data from promise `then`:

```
getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
  .then(function(data){
     console.log("Response "+JSON.parse(data).Country);
     return getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country);
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log("Data "+data)
  })
  .catch(function(err){
     console.log(err)
  });
```

Whatever you return from `then` callback, will be passed further down the promise chain. Right now you are not returning anything, thus implicitly returning `undefined`.

Comment: it works after adding return but I didn't understand this, 
 isn't call to getPromise already returning the promise.

Comment: Again: whatever you return *from* `then` callback gets passed into the next `then` callback. So if you want the promise returned by `getPromise` be available in the next `then` callback, you need to return it from the previous one.

Comment: I thought calling getPromise is actually returning the promise to next then. Thanks got it now

Answer (score 0):

You have to return data for next 'then' to receive it.

```
getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
      .then(function(data){
         console.log("Response "+JSON.parse(data).Country);
         return getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country);
      })
      .then(function(data){
        console.log("Data "+data)
      })
      .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might change the function

```
getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
      .then(function(data){
         console.log("Response "+JSON.parse(data).Country);
         getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country)
         .then(function(data){
           console.log("Data "+data)
         });
      })

      .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return`:

```
getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
  .then(function(data){
     console.log("Response "+JSON.parse(data).Country);

     /////////// here
     return getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country);
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log("Data "+data)
  })
  .catch(function(err){
     console.log(err)
  });
```